# Appcelerator Titanium(Android) webview's extra space

Tags: android, titanium

I am relatively new to titanium. I am loading my local html/xml in webview. In iOS everything is handled automatically(showing content) but when I check this in android content in webview has extra spaces also content is shown with jump and bounce which is never acceptable. I am using alloy structure.
when I statically add meta tag(viewport) in my local file, then white space is gone. But I require to load local files dynamically so I can't edit my local files.
So editing these files I override load method of webview like this :-

```
$.webview.addEventListener('load', function(e) { $.webview.evalJS("var m=document.createElement(\"meta\");m.name = \"viewport\";m.content = \"width=" + scrwidth + ", user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1\";document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(m);"); });
```

But it does not affect html of webview. For confirming this I write one file after evalJS so I can be sure that evalJS is affecting.

```
var jsString = 'var s=document.createElement("script");' + 's.innerHTML="' + 'sdfsdfsdfsd' + '";' + 'document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);'; $.webview.evalJS(jsString);

var resFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "response.html"); resFile.write($.webview.html);
```

Now when I check this file in application data directory I can see this effect for iOS(it shows only content of my local html) but for android I cant see my added script. When I check response file it starts with javascrit which I cant understand from where it comes(I think its from native webview's html) and after its script is ended I see my html but not the script which I added manually in load.
I read about this problem but all has given viewport meta tag solution but in my case No matter how much I am trying I am unable to fit content.
So can you guys tell me where I am going wrong? Is there any special permission to edit html of webview in android(because its not editing).

Application type :- mobile Titanium SDK :- 3.0.2 Platform & version :- Android 2.2 Device :- htc Nexus/ mototrola zoom Host operating system :- Mac OS 10.8.2 Titanium Studio :- 3.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer but as I have said that wherever I tried to find this questions answer I found the same answers as you mentioned(so definitely your answer is correct) but I have mentioned above that I cant add this line manually because I do not have control over these files so this will not work for me anymore.

I also shown that how I am dynamically adding meta tag above but that also did not work.

So now what I did is I took handle of file where html is saved and then replace `</head>`
tag with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1"></head>` and then saved this file to its own location. Now when file is successfully write I then access it using webview.url = file.nativepath. :) and now everything is working fine.

May be this is useful for someone who is trying same like me. Here process will be slow because I am accessing file editing file and then again access this file but this is at least working. If some one has more accurate or sensible answer they can answer here thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need the viewport meta tag for mobile devices:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for a solution to this as well. If I could give you 20 upvotes I would :-)